# Python how to pass form input value to payload

Tags: python, django, payload

I need to submit a form  to an API and I want to pass the form fields value to the Payload for a python request API, how can I achieve this?

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
trading_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
industry = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
vat = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
address_street = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
address_city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
address_postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
address_iso_country = CountryField(max_length=100, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ('trading_name', 'industry', 'vat', 'address_street',
              'address_city', 'address_postal_code', 'address_iso_country')
```

views.py

```
def upload_kyb(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    url = 'https://stoplight.io/mocks/railsbank/api/25652867/v1/customer/endusers'
    headers = {
              'Content-Type': "application/json",
              'Accept': "application/json",
              'Authorization': ""
        }
    payload = "{ \n \"company\": {\n    \"name\": \"Example Company\", \n    \"trading_name\": \"jiuliasu\",\n    \"industry\": \"Telecommunications\",\n    \"vat\": \"GB123456789\",\n    \"registration_address\": \n      {\n         \"address_refinement\": \"Floor 15\", \n         \"address_number\": \"20\", \n         \"address_street\": \"Floor 15\", \n         \"address_city\": \"London\", \n         \"address_postal_code\": \"SS8 9JH\", \n         \"address_iso_country\": \"GBR\" \n      }\n\t}\n}"
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
    print(payload)
    # form = Kybform(request.POST, request.FILES)
    form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('kyb_list')
else:
    
    form = BookForm()
return render(request, 'kybstart/upload_kyb.html', {
    'form': form
})
```

I can get the response in the console but how can I actually pass the form inputs dynamically into the Payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorted using f-string for the payload:

```
payload = f'{{  "company": {nl}, "name": {trading_name}, {nl}"industry": {industry}, {nl}"vat": {vat}, {nl}, "registration_address": {nl}, "address_number": {address_street}, {nl}"address_street": {address_city}}}'
```

and assign variable as per the answer above

```
trading_name = request.POST.get('trading_name')
    nl = '\n'
    industry = request.POST.get('industry')
    vat = request.POST.get('vat')
    address_street = request.POST.get('address_street')
    address_city = request.POST.get('address_city')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign variables to the items in your post then use the variables in your payload

You can break up the string with quotes and concatenate the variables.

Example
Payload = "Trading name: " + name_variable +" industry"